# write a batch script to find a sub directory

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting. I am to write a batch script which will search for a sub directory and then compare the extension of the files present inside the directory.
For example, for the following structure:

`D:\Batch_script\unknown_dir_name\destiantion1\dummy.txt`

My script should first find the directory *destiantion1* and then if it exist it should look for `dummy.txt` file.

Is it possible? can anyone please suggest me a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
    'dir /ad /s /b "d:\Batch_script\destiantion1"'
) do if exist "%%~f\dummy.txt" echo %%~f
```

For each directory named destiantion1 under d:\batch_script, if it contains a dummy.txt file, echo to console

EDITED - to adapt to comments

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
    'dir /ad /s /b "d:\Batch_script\destiantion1"'
) do if exist "%%~f\dummy.txt" (
    dir /a-d /b "%%~f\dummy.txt" 2>nul | find "dummy.txt" > nul && echo %%~f
)
```

`for` and `dir` commands do not differentiate upper and lower case at search, so, use a filter. If the string is found, no errorlevel is set and the code after `&&` is executed.

Other alternative is to process the complete list of files searching for the adecuated folder/file

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (
    'dir /a-d /s /b "d:\batch_script\dummy.txt" ^| findstr /l /e /c:"\destiantion1\dummy.txt"'
) do echo %%~dpf
```

Comment: Thanks it worked great. Is there any way that I can check case sensitive files with "if exist" command? because my dummy.txt file should always be in lower case letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am all set to go with the script now :)